# How to upload external data files to Wave Analytics using External Data API

Tags: soap-api, csv, einstein-analytics, analytics-api

I want to upload external data csv file to Salesforce Wave Analytics using External Data API and Web Services Connector (WSC).

I have connected to salesforce using below code:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
config.setAuthEndpoint(endpoint);
PartnerConnection partnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(config);
```

Now, I need to upload external data csv and dataflow to salesforce analytics using API.

Does anyone have an example of how to upload data into the Saleforce Analytics Cloud.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides an example.

After you have established the [PartnerConnection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_connect_to_sf.htm), which you have done, the remaining steps are to:

1. [Configure the Upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_configure_upload.htm)
   Setup the InsightsExternalData header with details about the upload. A name for the dataset, what operation to perform on the data.
2. [Add the Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_add_data.htm)
   Chunk the Data up in 10 MB chunks.
3. [Manage the Upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_manage_upload.htm)
   Set the Action to Process to get things going.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find here a tools on git that is implementing this API: https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils

Answer (score 0):

U can find this by this link..
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_overview.htm

Thanks and regards
Tanushree